# Deleted local repository created by git clone [https], now git clone [https] won't work

Tags: git

I git cloned a repository then deleted it the local clone. Turns out that I needed the repository after all so I tried to clone it again. I receive:

**fatal: unable to access [https]: The request URL returned error: 403.**

I have run rm -rf .git, I have used git pull origin master, I have created a new repository containing all the same files as the old repository but I still cannot git clone. It doesn't seem to matter what local directory I am in either. Strangely enough, I can clone ANY other repository just not this one. This leads me to believe there is some locally stored metadata that I am unaware of left over from the original deletion of the clone that I need to get rid of so that I can clone it again.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: Try cloning it again, but into a different local location?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for the suggestion. As stated in the original post, I have tried that to no avail.

Comment: `403` is "forbidden": the source hates you for some reason. Figure out why, perhaps.

Comment: Just an update: I went ahead and cloned a repository that I didn't need just to delete it with rm -rf [repository name]. This command deletes the locally stored repository but if I try to git clone again, it will not work. So in general, my issue is:

git clone [thing],
delete locally,
git clone again --> does not work.

So strange.

Comment: Total guess: the web site you're cloning *from* keeps track of who cloned what, and refuses to let them do it again the same day (or hour, or month, or some other time period). The point is, *they* are the one you have to ask, not *us*.

Comment: @torek Gotcha. I'd say that's a pretty good guess. If this ends up being the case, I'll post back with an update. Thanks!